# Duplicated element in AndroidManifest.xml with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, barcode-scanner, phonegap

The build process ends with the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED in 3s
(node:8976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    \platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-60 Error:
            Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-60 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-84
```

The problem is that i have these two lines in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

The only plugin installed is *phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner* (version 7.0.2) and here are the versions used:

- Cordova: 8.0.0
- Android: 7.0.0

How can I remove the duplicated entry in the XML file? Even if I remove it manually it obviously comes back after the next build process.

Comment: Remove the plugin first and then run it.
If runs successfully then add the plugin again and check it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a brand new app (but with the old assets), installed again both android platform and the plugin and everything works fine now.